# Filtering Json to show only the results the user wants

Tags: java, android, json, filter

In my app i can get the data in json and display it on a listview just fine, but now i want to filter, i want 3 different filters based on a field from each json object "estado".

I have the menu on action bar where the user can click the filter.

**My approach:**

For each menu item i did a function using `android:onClick="doC"` and each one changes the value of a integer "s" to 1, 2 or 3, so the AsyncTask gets this number and executes different tasks in order to filter.

```
 public void doC(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Concluidas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s = 1;
        new GetObras().execute();
    }

    public void doA(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aguardam Aprovação", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s = 2;
    }

    public void doR(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recusadas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s = 3;
}
```

To receive i changed the function signature to this:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
```

And then inside doInBackground i have:

```
if (s == 0) {
// do this
if (s == 1) {
//do this
}
```

I get no errors but after i click on the filter, he displayes the progress animation but nothing changes in the listview.

**Complete code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView list;
    int s;

    private static String url = "http://ploran.gear.host/scriptobras6.php";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> obrasList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> concluidasList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        obrasList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        concluidasList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

        new GetObras().execute();

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                Log.e("item clicks", "selected: " + position);

                Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", obrasList.get(position).get("Id"));
                intent.putExtra("nomeobra", obrasList.get(position).get("nomeObra"));
                intent.putExtra("idCliente", obrasList.get(position).get("idCliente"));
                intent.putExtra("dataplevantamento", obrasList.get(position).get("DataLevantamento"));
                intent.putExtra("datarlevantamento", obrasList.get(position).get("DataRealizacao"));
                intent.putExtra("estado", obrasList.get(position).get("Estado"));
                intent.putExtra("DataRMateriais", obrasList.get(position).get("DataRMateriais"));
                intent.putExtra("DataInicioObra", obrasList.get(position).get("DataInicioObra"));
                intent.putExtra("DataConclusao", obrasList.get(position).get("DataConclusao"));
                intent.putExtra("DataVestoria\"", obrasList.get(position).get("DataVestoria"));
                intent.putExtra("Obs", obrasList.get(position).get("Obs"));
                intent.putExtra("Prompor", obrasList.get(position).get("Prompor"));
                intent.putExtra("Levantpor", obrasList.get(position).get("Levantpor"));
                intent.putExtra("executpor", obrasList.get(position).get("executpor"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private class GetObras extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Por favor aguarde ...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            JSONArray obras = null;

            try {
                obras = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (s == 0) {
                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        //JSONArray obras = jsonObj.getJSONArray("obras");

                        // looping through All
                        for (int i = 0; i < obras.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = obras.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString("Id");
                            String nomeObra = c.getString("NomeObra");
                            String idCliente = c.getString("idCliente");
                            String DataLevantamento = c.getString("DataPLevantamento");
                            String DataRealizacao = c.getString("DataRLevantamento");
                            String Estado = c.getString("Estado");
                            String DataMateriais = c.getString("DataRMateriais");
                            String DataInicioObra = c.getString("DataInicioObra");
                            String DataConclusao = c.getString("DataConclusao");
                            String DataVestoria = c.getString("DataVestoria");
                            String Obs = c.getString("Obs");
                            String Prompor = c.getString("Prompor");
                            String Levantpor = c.getString("Levantpor");
                            String executpor = c.getString("executpor");

                            // tmp hash map for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> obra = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            obra.put("Id", id);
                            obra.put("nomeObra", nomeObra);
                            obra.put("idCliente", idCliente);
                            obra.put("DataLevantamento", DataLevantamento);
                            obra.put("DataRealizacao", DataRealizacao);
                            obra.put("Estado", Estado);
                            obra.put("DataMateriais", DataMateriais);
                            obra.put("DataIncioObra", DataInicioObra);
                            obra.put("DataConclusao", DataConclusao);
                            obra.put("DataVestoria", DataVestoria);
                            obra.put("Obs", Obs);
                            obra.put("Prompor", Prompor);
                            obra.put("Levantpor", Levantpor);
                            obra.put("executpor", executpor);

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            obrasList.add(obra);
                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            if ( s == 1) {
                JSONObject object = null;

                for (int i = 0; i < obras.length(); i++) {

                    try {
                        object = obras.getJSONObject(i);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        if (object.getString("Estado") == "Obra Concluída") {
                            JSONObject c = obras.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString("Id");
                            String nomeObra = c.getString("NomeObra");
                            String idCliente = c.getString("idCliente");
                            String DataLevantamento = c.getString("DataPLevantamento");
                            String DataRealizacao = c.getString("DataRLevantamento");
                            String Estado = c.getString("Estado");
                            String DataMateriais = c.getString("DataRMateriais");
                            String DataInicioObra = c.getString("DataInicioObra");
                            String DataConclusao = c.getString("DataConclusao");
                            String DataVestoria = c.getString("DataVestoria");
                            String Obs = c.getString("Obs");
                            String Prompor = c.getString("Prompor");
                            String Levantpor = c.getString("Levantpor");
                            String executpor = c.getString("executpor");

                            // tmp hash map for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> obra = new HashMap<>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            obra.put("Id", id);
                            obra.put("nomeObra", nomeObra);
                            obra.put("idCliente", idCliente);
                            obra.put("DataLevantamento", DataLevantamento);
                            obra.put("DataRealizacao", DataRealizacao);
                            obra.put("Estado", Estado);
                            obra.put("DataMateriais", DataMateriais);
                            obra.put("DataIncioObra", DataInicioObra);
                            obra.put("DataConclusao", DataConclusao);
                            obra.put("DataVestoria", DataVestoria);
                            obra.put("Obs", Obs);
                            obra.put("Prompor", Prompor);
                            obra.put("Levantpor", Levantpor);
                            obra.put("executpor", executpor);

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            obrasList.add(obra);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                }

            return null;
        }


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute (Void result){

                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    // Dismiss the progress dialog
                    if (pDialog.isShowing())
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, obrasList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"nomeObra", "idCliente",
                            "Estado"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    if(pDialog.isShowing()) { pDialog.hide(); }
                }
    }



    List<String> cities;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // User pressed the search button
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // User changed the text
        return false;
    }

    public void doC(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Concluidas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s = 1;
        new GetObras().execute();
    }

    public void doA(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Aguardam Aprovação", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s = 2;
    }

    public void doR(MenuItem item){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recusadas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        s = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you change the filter on the methods from the menu you change the Integer for filter but you dont call the AsyncTask ever again, put **new GetObras().execute();** inside 'doA' and 'doR'

Comment: make all other same like this `doC`

Comment: But i am doing on doC, thats the one im trying to do first.

Comment: just try it and tell us how it goes ^^

Comment: You only renew the data of the adapter after getting the result of an asynctask, if your way of resorting the items is querying the server again and when you change the integer that changes the way you query you dont send a new asynctask its logical you dont see changes, your not asking for it, its pretty weird it isnt working now, **can you show the way you are calling the menu clicks?**